# Haskell: Function as Typedeclaration

Tags: function, haskell, typeclass

I want to implement some functions for a graph.

The type declaration is:

```
type Graph = Knoten -> [Knoten]
```

For one function I have to go through the list `[Knoten]`. I have the right algorithm but don't know how to access `[Knoten]`.

Here are my attempts:

```
ist_minimal :: Graph -> Bool
ist_minimal g = minimalHelp g

minimalHelp :: Knoten -> [Knoten] -> Bool
minimalHelp _ [] = True
minimalHelp k (m:ms) 
 | elem m ms = False
 | otherwise = minimalHelp k ms
```

```
ist_minimal :: Graph -> Bool
ist_minimal (k ks) = minimalHelp (k ks)     --k=Knoten, ks=[Knoten]

minimalHelp :: Knoten -> [Knoten] -> Bool
minimalHelp _ [] = True
minimalHelp k (m:ms) 
 | elem m ms = False
 | otherwise = minimalHelp k ms
```

My consideration was, that when

```
Graph = Knoten -> [Knoten]
```

it is possible to write Graph as `Knoten [Knoten]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. `Knoten -> [Knoten] -> Bool` means `Knoten -> ([Knoten] -> Bool)` while `Graph -> Bool` means `(Knoten -> [Knoten]) -> Bool` and those are very different types.

Basically the only thing you can do with a `Knoten -> [Knoten]` (and so with a `Graph`) is to invoke it on some `Knoten`, so your function will need to be built from this operation. E.g. one possible `ist_minimal :: Graph -> Knoten` which calls `minimal_help` would be

```
ist_minimal g = minimal_help k (g k)
    where k = ...
```

and `...` will need to be filled to give you something of type `Knoten`: `g k` will have type `[Knoten]` and so this code passes a `Knoten` and a `[Knoten]` to `minimal_help`, as its type requires.

Comment: Also good to note that `ist_minimal g = minimal_help <*> g`, using the `Applicative` instance for functions.

Comment: @chepner I think that for someone asking questions like this one it's far too early and would only distract :)

Comment: Not suggesting that one should use it, but I've found it useful to see when a pattern I am given (or have stumbled on myself) is in fact captured by a higher abstraction. If nothing else, it's just one more example that will help build intuition for how `Applicative` works.